# Why do I see a spike of steps per second in tensorflow training initially?

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Hi tensorflow experts,

I see the following training speed profile using dataset API and prefetching of 128, 256, 512, or 1024 batches (each of 128 examples):

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into

INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.969178, step = 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 70.3812
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.65544295, step = 100 (1.422 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 178.33
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.47716027, step = 200 (0.560 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 178.626
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.53073615, step = 300 (0.560 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 132.039
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.4849593, step = 400 (0.757 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 121.437
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.4055175, step = 500 (0.825 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 122.379
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.28230205, step = 600 (0.817 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 122.163
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.4917924, step = 700 (0.819 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 122.509
```

The initial spike of 178 steps per second is reproducible across multiple runs and different prefetching amount. I am trying to understanding the underlying multi-threading mechanism on why that happens.

Additional information:
my cpu usage peaks at 1800% on a 48 core machine. My gpu usage is consistently at only 9%. So it's pretty amazing that both of these are not exhausted. So I am wondering if the mutex in queue_runner is causing the cpu processing to not realize its full potential, as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/583)?

Thanks,

John

[update] I also observed the same spike when I use prefetch_to_device(gpu_device, ..), with similar buffer sizes. Surprisingly, prefetch_to_device only slows things down, by about 10%.

```
NFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into 

INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.3881096, step = 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 52.3374
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.48779136, step = 100 (1.910 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 121.154
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.3451385, step = 200 (0.827 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 89.3222
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.37804496, step = 300 (1.119 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 80.4857
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.49938473, step = 400 (1.242 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 79.1798
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.5120025, step = 500 (1.263 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 81.2081
```

Answer (score 1):

It's common to see spikes in steps per second at the start of each training run, as the cpu had time to fill up the buffer. Your step per seconds are very reasonable compared to the start, but the lack of cpu usage might indicate a bottleneck.

First question is, whether or not you are using the Dataset API in combination with the estimator. From your terminal output I suspect you do, if not I would start by changing your code to use the Estimator class. If you are already using the Estimator class, then make sure you are following the best performance practices as documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance).

If your are doing all of the above already, then there is a bottleneck in you pipeline. Due to the low CPU usage I would guess you are experiencing an I/O bottleneck. You might have your Dataset on a slow medium (hard-drive) or you aren't using a serialized format and are saturating the IOPS  (again hard-drive or network storage). In either case, start by using a serialized data format such as TF-records and upgrade your storage to SSD or multiple hard drives in raid 1,0,10 your pick.

Comment: Thanks! How do I diagnose and verify IO bottleneck? I tried iostat and everything looks pretty under-utilized. My disk can handle > 1G/s throughput. I am already using tfrecord, but not SSD.